# Git revert merge commit, lost some files

Tags: git, merge

So I've merged wrongly my `feature` branch on `release` and pushed.
Then reverted it back, with a reverse commit of the merge commit, and everithing went well.

The problem shows up when trying to merge `release` onto `master`, noticed some missing files and weird changes. The problem turns more scaring when that corrupt merge is actually pushed on my `master` branch

Looking back into revert merge commit `(W1)`, I see all those missing files where file deletions in the reverse commit.

Keeping in mind that the `feature` branch is going to be merged anyways on the `master`, I was thinking on rebase -i from `master` on that reverse commit `(W1)` and go ahead just like that merge was done without reverse commit.

Do you think there's a better solution??

Thank you all! :)
[image]

## EDIT

First of all, thanks for your attention and response! I've added some things on the picture to better explain the situation.
Actually we dont care anymore of the `release` branch in the picture, it only affects a few files and can be present on `master` without any major problems. The file addition and modification where made in `master` between the creation of `release` and `feature`.

I'm triying to rebase the master branch, after the release merge `(M2)` deleting  `(W1)`. I know that we are loosing some `release` history, but I think it's a better solution to "save" the actual released code and if it becomes necessary, we can start a repo from it.
There are like 1000 commits to rebase, and some conflicts are sowing up. I'm correcting every evident conflict with the latest correct version of each file.

## EDIT 2

Finally we rebased the `master` branch, and then applied differences at the top of the branch, like a "fake rebase", in this way the changes are visible and alterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** :

Based on your updated question, I see why the file deletions occur. It seems like an unusual combination of circumstances to me.  Most interesting point is that the revert of a merge is a more dangerous operation than it seemed to me at first glance.  Undoing the merge (by resetting to clear it from history before it's been pushed) is the typical procedure and would avoid this kind of problem - if the problem had been caught prior to the push.  But that's not much help here and now.

The clarifications notwithstanding, I still recommend against the history edit you propose and all of my advice relative to that edit is contained in my original answer.  Keep in mind that if you rebase `master` in a way that edits commits from `release`, `release` will still have the original commits and you will have a weird, splintered history prone to conflicts on certain merge operations (because of duplicate commits doing the same things).

If you want to put all the changes from M1 back into the history, you can do that with fewer headaches by reverting W1.  You still may get a handful of conflicts, but it's a much simpler procedure to begin with; doesn't create upstream rebase problems; and exposes you to fewer conflicted merges down the road.

---

It sounds like you're considering editing the history of the release branch.  I recommend against it both for short-term reasons (the "upstream rebase" resoultion that will be required) and long-term reasons (the release branch would no longer document what was released).  Of course I may have misunderstood what you're proposing, so let's get to a common starting point:

You currently have something like

```
O --- x --- x --- x --- M2 <--(master)
 \     \               /
  \     x --- M1 --- W1 <--(release)
   \         /
    A ----- B --- C --- D <--(feature)
```

where `M1` was a mistaken merge of `feature` into `release`, `W1` reverted `M1`, and `M2` was the eventual merge of `release` into `master`.

As I understand it, all of that has been pushed, some of it is reflected in the history of your release version, and the "problem" commits are also already part of the shared history of `master`.  So if it were me I'd consider nearly all of it "written in stone".

If you do ultimately decide to use rebase to "fix" the release branch, two things to consider:

1) It would be best to remove `M1` *and* `W1` from the release branch history, so that at least its resultant tree is a correct reflection of what you released.  (I realize that eventually the work from `M1` will be re-introduced, but that's not what you released.)

2) Having done that, you'd have to redo the `M2` merge (creating `M2'`) using the new `release` ref, and then rebase `master`, and anything else that has been branched from `master` since `M2`, to `M2'`.  It can spiderweb quickly if this is an active repo.

And that's why I just wouldn't.  So what else could you do?

It sounds like the `release` came out looking as it should, and so it's unclear to me why this would have any ill effects on `master` *until you try to merge `feature`*.  After all, if removal of a file was done in `W1` then that file must've been added (from perspective of `release`) by `M1`, so there would not normally be any net change when applying this to `master`.  If `master` is messed up even though it doesn't contain `feature`, more info may be needed to understand why (and what to do about it).

(Or OTOH, if `feature` *has* already been merged to `master` at the time you started trying to merge `release` to master - which would explain why the merge looked like a mess - then that would require a different resolution that what I've suggested below.)

But if, as it sounds from the question, you *haven't* yet merged `feature`, then when you *do* try to merge `feature` to `master`, I would expect git to think `A` and `B` (which ultimately added the file) have already been applied through `M1`.  (Subsequent changes in `W1` then happen to undo it, but git doesn't much care.)

What I guess you need are new commits that do what `A` and `B` did.  You can get that with *relatively* little headache by rebasing `feature` to `M2` (or later on `master`).  The problem is that if you tell rebase that `master` is your upstream, it will skip `A` and `B` (because those are reachable from `master`); so you have to force the upstream to be commit `O`.

So you could look up the SHA value for `O`, or put a tag on it (say `feature-root`) and then

```
git rebase --onto master feature-root feature
```

yielding

```
                          A' --- B' --- C' --- D' <--(feature)
                         /
O --- x --- x --- x --- M2 <--(master)
 \     \               /
  \     x --- M1 --- W1 <--(release)
   \         /
    A ----- B --- C --- D
```

So `C` and `D` don't matter (`gc` will eventually reclaim them), `A` and `B` (and `M1`) are left alone in history (avoiding the most problematic upstream rebases), and only users who are sharing the `feature` ref need to worry about upstream rebase recovery.

Comment: Thanks for response, I've studied what you said and I explained the situation a little better in the main post